# How can I configure BIOS to boot-up automatically at a particular time?

Tags: boot, bios, scheduled-tasks

The code sandbox is huge (including support libraries and stuff it is several hundred MB). The initial checkout+build procedure takes close to 45 minutes. A script executes the download+build procedure (which runs as a service so build executes automagically after the computer boot-up).

Policy dictates a full check-out in the morning. Said policy also dictates system shut-down at night ... so the system may not be left running overnight.

My problem is the boot-up must happen manually hence the question -  Is it possible to configure the BIOS to boot the system at a particular time each morning?

Comment: Do they require shut down or is Sleep or Hibernate acceptable? Also, if you can get us your BIOS type/version we may be able to give more specific instructions. Is Wake-On-LAN a possibility?

Comment: Also, it sounds as though this is a business and I'd assume the company probably recognizes the lost hours of work due to these policies. Have you tried asking the IT staff if they are working to find some solution? Management would probably love to find some way around these policies, especially if you can tell them they could increase usable work-time per developer by 12%.

Comment: Sleep/hibernate is 'unacceptable'. They want a shut-down; it's part of a lights-out/energy conservation policy ... which I disagree with because sleep will probably save almost as much energy as a shut-down. IT staff recommended virtual machines ; no telling when that will happen. In the interim "developers can recommend additional methods to improve morale and productivity".

Answer (score 4):

This is a very BIOS specific question, which can not be answered in general as there are hundreds of different BIOSs/Mainboards. You have to check you BIOS manual for said support. You can also check if you mainboard supports remote management.

One thing you could also consider is, to manage the morning reboot from OS side.

Comment: Could you elaborate the last line about morning reboot from OS please?

Comment: @Everyone Well, that again is total different question, but I am sure there are ways how you can configure your system to schedule shutdown and reboot.

Comment: Like I said in the original post. Shutdown must happen at end-of-day. Schedule Shutdown yes. Schedule reboot yes. 

But schedule boot-up at some _specified duration_ after_ shut-down is, to the best of my knowledge, not supported on Microsoft OSes.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated: That depends on your BIOS and motherboard but there might be another solution.

If your motherboards supports wake-on-lan and the computer has a dedicated IP you can use a service like www.wakeonlan.me to boot up your computer. You just specify the IP, MAC and date/time and it will take care of the rest. That has worked fine for me previously.

Comment: It will not work if you’re behind a NAT.

Comment: +1: Thanks for the try; It won't work in my situation, but doesn't mean it might not be useful for somebody else if they have an open IP.